# How do I detect if the NavigationBar component is active?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

In Vuetify 3 using the NavigationDrawer component, how do I detect that the NavigationDrawer is not active, so I can make necessary changes to variables in the App.vue?

I had this working in Vuetify 2 where I passed a prop into the NavigationDrawer from App.js and when the NavigationDrawer closed the variable was set to false.  Now, on the first pass through you open the NavigationDrawer with one click on the hamburger icon in the AppBar.vue and subsequent navigations require a double click on the hamburger icon to reset the variable passed into the NavigationDrawer as a prop.  I need to detect that the NavigationDrawer is not active, so I can update the variable in App.vue.  Currently the function updateNavDrawerHandler is only invoked when the hamburger icon is clicked.  I need to invoke this function when the NavigationDrawer closes.

Below is the code from the three relevant files.

AppBar.vue contains the navigation drawer hamburger icon:

```
        <template>
            <v-app-bar app color='primary' dark>
                <div class='d-flex app-viewport'>
                    <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-if='user.isLoggedIn && $vuetify.display.smAndDown' @click='updateNavDrawerHandler'>
                    </v-app-bar-nav-icon>
                </div>
            </v-app-bar>
        </template>

        <script lang='ts'>
        import { defineComponent, Ref, ref, toRaw, watch } from 'vue';
        import { useUserStore } from '@/store/userStore/index';
        import { User } from '@/models/domain/user';

        export default defineComponent({
            name: 'AppBar',
            emits: ['user-logging-in', 'user-logging-out', 'user-signing-up', 'update-nav-drawer'],
            setup(props, { emit }) {
                const userStore = useUserStore();
                const user: Ref<User> = ref(userStore.getUser);
                const updateNavDrawerHandler = (): void => {
                    emit('update-nav-drawer', null, null);
                };
                watch(
                    () => userStore.getUser,
                    () => {
                        user.value = toRaw(userStore.getUser);
                    }
                );
                return {
                    user,
                    updateNavDrawerHandler,
                };
            },
        });
        </script>
```

Here is App.vue that takes the value from AppBar and passes it to NavigationDrawer as a prop:

```
        <template>
            <v-app>
                <div class='app-viewport'>
                    <NavigationDrawer :navDrawerStatus='navDrawerStatus' :userLoggedIn='user.isLoggedIn' />
                    <app-bar 
                        v-on:update-nav-drawer='updateNavDrawerHandler' />
                    <v-main>
                        <router-view />
                    </v-main>
                </div>
            </v-app>
        </template>

        <script lang='ts'>
        import {
            defineComponent,
            Ref,
            ref,
            toRaw,
            watch,
        } from 'vue';
        import { useUserStore } from '@/store/userStore/index';
        import AppBar from '@/components/navigation/AppBar.vue';
        import NavigationDrawer from '@/components/navigation/NavigationDrawer.vue';
        import { User } from '@/models/domain/user';

        export default defineComponent({
            name: 'App',
            components: {
                AppBar,
                NavigationDrawer,
            },
            setup() {
                // Initialize stores
                const userStore = useUserStore();

                // Navbar functionality
                const navDrawerStatus: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
                const updateNavDrawerHandler = (): void => {
                    navDrawerStatus.value = !navDrawerStatus.value;
                };

                // User set up
                const user: Ref<User> = ref(
                    toRaw(userStore.getUser)
                );
                watch(
                    () => userStore.getUser,
                    () => {
                        user.value = toRaw(userStore.getUser);
                    }
                );

                return {
                    user,
                    navDrawerStatus,
                    updateNavDrawerHandler,
                };
            },
        });
        </script>
```

Finally, here is the code for the NavigationDrawer.vue

```
        <template>
            <v-navigation-drawer app color='secondary' :model-value='navDrawerStatus' v-if='userLoggedIn'>
            </v-navigation-drawer>
        </template>

        <script lang='ts'>
        import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

        export default defineComponent({
            name: 'NavigationDrawer',
            props: {
                navDrawerStatus: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: false
                },
                userLoggedIn: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: false
                },
            },
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "active" NavigationBar, which also isn't a component in Vuetify.  Do you mean app-bar or maybe navigation drawer?  Does active refer to a v-model like for hamburger menu, or something else?  Including some code would help clear up what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the navigation drawer.  Sorry for the confusion.  The relevent code is in three different vue files.  I'm editing it down to the relevant code and will edit the question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to this issue. NavigationDrawer emits the following when the modelValue changes: @update:modelValue.  The only change to the code occurs in App.vue and is as follows:

```
@update:modelValue="(modelValue: boolean) => closeNavDrawerHandler(modelValue)"
```

You would then of course write the logic for the closeNavDrawerHandler function.

The full updated code for App.vue is as follows:

```
    <template>
        <v-app>
            <div class='app-viewport'>
                <NavigationBar :navDrawerStatus='navDrawerStatus' :userLoggedIn='user.isLoggedIn'
                    @update:modelValue="(modelValue: boolean) => closeNavDrawerHandler(modelValue)" />
                <app-bar v-on:user-logging-in='user.isLoggingIn = true' v-on:user-logging-out='logoutHandler'
                    v-on:user-signing-up='user.isSigningUp = true' v-on:update-nav-drawer='updateNavDrawerHandler' />
                <v-main>
                    <router-view />
                    <v-dialog v-model='userIsLoggingIn' persistent :fullscreen='isSmallViewPort' :max-width='maxDialogWidth'
                        hide-overlay transition='dialog-top-transition'>
                        <LoginForm :formStatus='userIsLoggingIn' v-on:cancel-login='user.isLoggingIn = false'
                            v-on:obtain-login-assistance='openLoginAssistanceHandler' />
                    </v-dialog>
                    <v-dialog v-model='userIsSigningUp' persistent :fullscreen='isSmallViewPort' :max-width='maxDialogWidth'
                        hide-overlay transition='dialog-top-transition'>
                        <SignUpForm :formStatus='userIsSigningUp' v-on:cancel-signup='user.isSigningUp = false' />
                    </v-dialog>
                    <v-dialog v-model='userObtainingLoginAssistance' persistent :fullscreen='isSmallViewPort'
                        :max-width='maxDialogWidth' hide-overlay transition='dialog-top-transition'>
                        <LoginAssistanceForm :formStatus='userObtainingLoginAssistance'
                            v-on:go-back-to-login='closeLoginAssistanceHandler' />
                    </v-dialog>
                </v-main>
            </div>
            <div>
                <v-footer>
                    <footer-nav />
                </v-footer>
            </div>
        </v-app>
    </template>

    <script lang='ts'>
    import {
        computed,
        ComputedRef,
        defineComponent,
        onMounted,
        onUnmounted,
        Ref,
        ref,
        toRaw,
        watch,
    } from 'vue';
    import { toast } from 'vue3-toastify';
    import 'vue3-toastify/dist/index.css';
    import { useAppStore } from '@/store/appStore/index';
    import { useSudokuStore } from '@/store/sudokuStore/index';
    import { useUserStore } from '@/store/userStore/index';
    import { useValuesStore } from '@/store/valuesStore/index';
    import AppBar from '@/components/navigation/AppBar.vue';
    import FooterNav from '@/components/navigation/FooterNav.vue';
    import NavigationBar from '@/components/navigation/NavigationBar.vue';
    import LoginForm from '@/components/forms/LoginForm.vue';
    import LoginAssistanceForm from '@/components/forms/LoginAssistanceForm.vue';
    import SignUpForm from '@/components/forms/SignUpForm.vue'
    import commonUtilities from '@/utilities/common';
    import { User } from '@/models/domain/user';

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            AppBar,
            FooterNav,
            NavigationBar,
            LoginForm,
            LoginAssistanceForm,
            SignUpForm
        },
        setup() {
            // Initialize stores
            const appStore = useAppStore();
            const sudokuStore = useSudokuStore();
            const userStore = useUserStore();
            const valuesStore = useValuesStore();

            // Navbar functionality
            const navDrawerStatus: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
            const updateNavDrawerHandler = (): void => {
                navDrawerStatus.value = !navDrawerStatus.value;
            };
            const closeNavDrawerHandler = (modelValue: boolean): void => {
                if (modelValue === false && navDrawerStatus.value === true) {
                    navDrawerStatus.value = modelValue;
                    appStore.updateNavDrawerStatus(navDrawerStatus.value);
                }
            };

            // User set up
            const user: Ref<User> = ref(
                toRaw(userStore.getUser)
            );
            watch(
                () => userStore.getUser,
                () => {
                    user.value = toRaw(userStore.getUser);
                }
            );

            // Login/logout functionality
            const { getLicense } = commonUtilities();
            const userObtainingLoginAssistance: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
            const userIsLoggingIn: ComputedRef<boolean> = computed(() => {
                return user.value?.isLoggingIn;
            });
            const logoutHandler = (): void => {
                const userName = user.value.userName;
                appStore.logout();
                appStore.updateToken('');
                toast(`${userName}, you are logged out.`, {
                    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                    type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
                });
            };
            const openLoginAssistanceHandler = (): void => {
                user.value.isLoggingIn = false;
                userObtainingLoginAssistance.value = true;
            }
            const closeLoginAssistanceHandler = (): void => {
                user.value.isLoggingIn = true;
                userObtainingLoginAssistance.value = false;
            }
            watch(
                () => user.value.isLoggingIn,
                () => {
                    userStore.updateUser(user.value);
                }
            );
            watch(
                () => userStore.getUserIsLoggedIn,
                () => {
                    const isLoggedIn = toRaw(userStore.getUserIsLoggedIn);
                    const isSignedUp = toRaw(userStore.getUserIsSignedIn);
                    if (isLoggedIn) {
                        navDrawerStatus.value = true;
                        let toastMessage: string;
                        user.value = toRaw(userStore.getUser);
                        if (!isSignedUp) {
                            toastMessage = `Welcome back ${user.value.userName}!`;
                        } else {
                            toastMessage = `Welcome to Sudoku Collective ${user.value.userName}!`;
                            user.value.isSignedUp = false;
                            userStore.updateUser(user.value);
                        }
                        toast(toastMessage, {
                            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                            type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
            watch(
                () => userStore.getConfirmedUserName,
                () => {
                    const confirmedUserName = userStore.getConfirmedUserName;
                    if (confirmedUserName !== '') {
                        closeLoginAssistanceHandler();
                    }
                }
            );
            watch(
                () => appStore.getServiceMessage,
                () => {
                    const serviceMessage = appStore.getServiceMessage;
                    if (serviceMessage === 'Status Code 200: Processed password reset request' || serviceMessage === 'Status Code 200: Resent password reset request') {
                        toast(serviceMessage, {
                            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                            type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,
                        });
                        user.value.isLoggingIn = false;
                        userObtainingLoginAssistance.value = false;
                        appStore.updateServiceMessage('');
                    }
                }
            );

            // Sign up functionality
            const userIsSigningUp: ComputedRef<boolean> = computed(() => {
                return user.value?.isSigningUp;
            });
            watch(
                () => user.value.isSigningUp,
                () => {
                    userStore.updateUser(user.value);
                }
            );

            // Dialog formatting
            const isSmallViewPort: Ref<boolean> = ref(true);
            const maxDialogWidth: Ref<string> = ref('auto');
            const resetAppViewPort = (): void => {
                if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
                    isSmallViewPort.value = true;
                    maxDialogWidth.value = 'auto';
                } else {
                    isSmallViewPort.value = false;
                    maxDialogWidth.value = '960px';
                }
            };

            // Lifecycle hooks
            onMounted(() => {
                appStore.addLicense(getLicense());
                valuesStore.initializeAsync();
                sudokuStore.initializeStore();
                resetAppViewPort();
                window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                    resetAppViewPort();
                });
            });
            onUnmounted(() => {
                window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {
                    resetAppViewPort();
                });
            });

            return {
                isSmallViewPort,
                maxDialogWidth,
                user,
                navDrawerStatus,
                closeNavDrawerHandler,
                userObtainingLoginAssistance,
                userIsLoggingIn,
                userIsSigningUp,
                logoutHandler,
                openLoginAssistanceHandler,
                closeLoginAssistanceHandler,
                updateNavDrawerHandler,
            };
        },
    });
    </script>

    <style lang='scss'>
    @import '@/assets/styles/site.scss';
    </style>
```